# Replace spaces by hyphen but not around comma

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a situation where I want to replace a `string` with single `-` I able to achieve this but the problem is

```
var str = "Beco de    Santo António BT, Cascais , Portugal";  // input
```

**output**

```
Beco-de-Santo-António-BT,-Cascais-,-Portugal  // output
```

But you can see `, Cascais , Portugal` I'm getting ==> `,-Cascais-,-Portugal`

**My desired output:**

```
 Beco-de-Santo-António-BT,Cascais,Portugal
```

```js
var str = "Beco de    Santo António BT, Cascais , Portugal";


str2 = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

alert(str2);
```

Comment: First remove all spaces around commas and then replace spaces by hyphen. `str.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ',').replace(/\s+/g, '-')`

Comment: jQuery is not needed so I removed both the jQuery tag and library from snippet.

Comment: With single `replace`: `.replace(/\s*,\s*|\s+/g, (m) => m.trim() ? ',' : '-')`

Comment: `str.replace(/\b\s+\b/g, '-').replace(/\s+/g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to target the white space between words.

```js
var str = "Beco de    Santo António BT, Cascais , Portugal";


str2 = str.replace(/\b\s+\b/g, '-');

alert(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str = "Beco de    Santo António BT, Cascais , Portugal";

str2 = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/,-/g, ',').replace(/-,/g, ',');

alert(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "Beco de    Santo António BT, Cascais , Portugal";

str2 = str.replace(/ , /g, ', ');
str2 = str2.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
str2 = str2.replace(/,-/g, ',');

alert(str2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, it is the simplest one. Happy to help!

Comment: I think this tops my list of "gratuitous jQuery inclusions". ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "Beco de    Santo António BT, Cascais , Portugal";
array = str.split(",");
array = $.map(array, function(value){
   return $.trim(value).replace(/\s\s+/g, '-').replace(/ /g, '-');
});
str = array.join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

This does your job:

```
function showInput(){
    var str = "Beco de    Santo António BT, Cascais , Portugal";
    var res = str.split(",");
    for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
        res[i] = res[i].trim();
        res[i] = res[i].replace(/\s+/g, '-');
    }
    var output = res.join();
    alert(output);
}
```

What I am doing is I am splitting the string using the commas and putting them into an array then iterating through the array.
In each iteration, I'm removing the leading and trailing whitespaces, then replacing the remaining whitespaces in between to be replaced with the hyphen (all done inplace) and then in the end, joining them together with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "Beco de    Santo António BT, Cascais , Portugal";


str2 = str.replace(/\w\s+\w/g, function(match, index){ return match.replace(/\s+/g, '-') });

alert(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the extra spaces which are nearby the `,` then replace the spaces inside strings by `-`

```
str.replace(/\s*,[,\s]*/g,',') // first remove spaces nearby  commas
   .replace(/\s+/g,'-'); // then replace them by -
```

```js
var str = "Beco de    Santo António BT, Cascais , Portugal";
str2 = str.replace(/\s*,[,\s]*/g,',').replace(/\s+/g,'-');
console.log(str2);
```